# Optimizing a simple mysql select on a large table (75M+ rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

I have a statistics table which grows at a large rate (around 25M rows/day) that I'd like to optimize for selects, the table fits in memory, and the server has plenty of spare memory (32G, table is 4G).

My simple roll-up query is:

```
EXPLAIN select FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(endtime/3600)*3600) as ts,sum(numevent1) as success , sum(numevent2) as failure from stats where endtime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600*96 group by ts order by ts;
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stats        | ALL  | ts            | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 78238584 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Stats is an innodb table, there is a normal index on endtime.. How should I optimize this?

Note: I do plan on adding roll-up tables, but currently this is what I'm stuck with, and I'm wondering if its possible to fix it without additional application code.

Comment: What alternatives have you tried with your query to try to get rid of the filesort? Have you tried removing the ordering? Have you tried examining your server configuration to see if it's set up to use enough memory?

Comment: I don't believe indexes work on Calculated Fields in MySql - any way for you to replace those?

Comment: It would help if you could explain what this query is trying to accomplish. Dividing and then multiplying by 3600 seems redundant. The group by and order by add a ton of time. You're ordering by an unindexed value which adds a ton of time.  If you have to order, order by the endtime field and make sure it's indexed.

Comment: @fartfrog: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: @CFreak: The dividing and multiplying rounds to the nearest hour. I'm ordering by ts, which is based off endtime, which, as stated in my question, is indexed.

Comment: You don't really want an index since you are scanning a range of data and placing them into buckets.  What you really want to do is partition the data so that you don't scan everything, just the latest range you are interested in. Rollup tables that you mentioned make sense. If you run the query often over the same ranges of data, then it is better to pre-compute the data/buckets once rather than on each query. Really need to distinguish between detailed "debug" data and summarized "stats" data.

Comment: Holy crap. Running a group by and order by in a query which is considering over 78M rows? How long is it taking now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing local tests. Try the following:

```
alter table stats add index (endtime, numevent1, numevent2);
```

And remove the `order by` as it should be implicit in the `group by` (I guess the parser just ignores the `order by` in this case, but just in case :)

Comment: This cuts down the query time by a factor of 10 (3 minutes to run the same query now). Any other tips?

Comment: Nice :) No, nothing I can think about

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using InnoDB you can also try the following:

a) Change innodb_buffer_pool_size to 24GB (requires server restart) - which will ensure that your whole table can be loaded into memory therefore will speed up sorting even as the table grows larger

b) Add innodb_file_per_table which causes InnoDB to place each new table space in its own table. Needs you to drop existing table and recreate it

c) Use the smallest available column size which can fit the data. Without seeing the actual column definitions and some sample, I cannot provide any specific ideas. Can you provide a sample schema and maybe 5 rows of data